# Shouldn't LED blink 25 (30) times per second on AC?

Tags: led, ac

I have told my friend that if is AC changing polarity 50 (60) times per second it means that LED (Diode) should blink only if the + nad - is on a right spot. We have tried that and oscillator showed as only the positive sine wave but the LED still blinks 50 times per second not 25. Why doesn't it blinks only 25 times.

It is just a transformer, resistor and LED powered by mains voltage (250V AC, 50Hz)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please edit your question to include a circuit schematic of the setup - is it a half-wave rectifier or full-wave - and part numbers for the LED and link to the datasheet. There's an easy-to-use schematic tool built in to the editor toolbar.

Comment: I think you are confused by the sine wave thing. The voltage goes high 50 times a second and low 50 times a second. The LED will therefore blink 50 times a second. Interestingly, if you full wave rectify the AC, the LED will blink 100 times per second, with two very short off times per cycle.

Comment: I want to know how you timed that it was blinking 50 times a sec?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confused by the sine wave thing. The voltage goes high 50 times a second and low 50 times a second.

[image]

The LED is a diode, and basically half wave rectifies this AC signal. It will therefore only light during each half cycle. It will blink 50 times a second with almost a 50% duty cycle.

[image]

Interestingly, if you full wave rectify the AC, the LED will blink 100 times per second with a very short off time per half AC cycle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKGNOI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your AC power is 50 Hz, there are 50 complete cycles (positive and negative) per second, so I would expect the LED to light on each positive half-cycle - 50 times per second.